# Relation of equivalence and equivalence class

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory, relations, equivalence-relations

(ZFC)Prove that the two conditions are equivalent:

- S/~≤T & T≤S
- ∃f (f:S↠T & ∀s1∀s2(f(s1)=f(s2)⇒s1~s2)).

My attempt: I start with the first, trying to prove the second.

1. S/~ is defined as the union of all equivalent classes of the form [a]/~, such that a ∈ S.
   Hence S/ is the number of proper classes of S/~, such that ∪([a]/~|a∈ S).
2. Since T≤S ⇒∃(f:S↠T) and f is not an injection.

Proof: Let x1 and x2 be two arbitrary elements from S.
Since the number of elements of S is bigger than those in T⇒ under *some condition* f(x1)=f(x2).

3. But from AC it follows that if S/~ consists of pairwise disjoint non-empty sets, there exists at least one set C, such that it contains exactly one element in common with each of the sets in S/~.
   Hence ∃(g:S⤖C) and since T≤C.
4. But from def of proper classes, namely ∀s1∀s2(<s1,s2> ∈ S/~ ⇒ Comp~(s1,s2)⇔f(s1)=f(s2).

Not sure wether it works, so please help me.

Comment: Consider using MathJax next time for better clarity. You can see some tips on how to use it here https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @AlejandroBergasaAlonso Okay, thank you so much!

Comment: you're welcome!!

Comment: Without assuming *surjectivity* of map $f$ in the second bullet point, the condition $|T|\le |S|$ in the first bullet point doesn't follow.

Comment: @Berci Not sure that I understand what you want to say.

Comment: When you write $f:S\to T$ in second bullet point, do you mean that $T$ is the *range*  of the function? If not, i.e. range of $f$ is only a *subset* of $T$, then the statement is not true in this form.

Comment: @Berci  Yes I mean that T is the range. But would you please tell me wether my attempt to solve it is correct?

Comment: I'm not sure I can follow. For example your point 2. is unclear, if $|T|\le|S|$ then we have an injective map $T\to S$.

Comment: @Berci I understand you. But in two I say that f is a surjection and not an injection. I think that f cannot be an injection, since the power of T< than the power of S, hence some elements in S will have the same image under ∼. But since ∼ is a class of equivalence, it proper classes coincide if and only if the sets themselves are ∼ comparable. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 1):

In its current format (i.e., without assuming that range of $f$ is $T$), the second bullet point is equivalent to $|S/{\sim}|\le |T|$.

Indeed, if a function $f:S\to T$ satisfies $f(s_1)=f(s_2)\implies s_1\sim s_2$, then, using axiom of choice, choose a representative of every equivalence class by a function $u:S/{\sim}\,\to S$ that satisfies $\pi\circ u={\rm id}$ where $\pi:S\to S/{\sim}$ is the natural map $\pi(s)=[s]_\sim$.
Then the condition on $f$ implies that $f\circ u:S/{\sim}\,\to T$ is injective.

For the other direction, if $g:S/{\sim}\,\to T$ is injective, then the composition $g\circ\pi:S\to T$ satisfies the condition.

---

If, moreover $f$ in second bullet point is assumed to be surjective, then it also implies $|T|\le |S|$ (by taking any right inverse of $f$, which exists by the axiom of choice).

Finally, assuming injections $g:S/{\sim}\,\to T$ and $h:T\to S$, we can define $f$ so that
$\quad f(s)=t\quad$ if $h(t)=s$ and $t\notin{\rm range}(g)$
$\quad f(s)=g([s]_\sim)\quad$ otherwise,
then its range is $T$ by construction, and verify that it satisfies $f(s_1)=f(s_2)\implies s_1\sim s_2$.